# C# Struct default value changes after creating new objects

Tags: c#

I'm currently taking a C# course and trying to solve this assignment but I can't get this one test working.

```
public struct RequestNumber {
        private static int _sequence;
        public int Sequence { get { return _sequence; } }

        public RequestNumber(int number)
        {
            _sequence = number;
        }

        public static RequestNumber CreateNext()
        {
            if (number + 1 >= 1 && number + 1 <= 50)
            {
                _sequence = number + 1;
            }
            else {
                _sequence = 1
            }
            return new RequestNumber(Sequence);
        }
    }
```

I made this piece of code to create a RequestNumber. The RequestNumber has a sequence and you can use the static method CreateNext() to create a new RequestNumber that has the next sequence between 1 and 50.

I also created a simple Request class that has a property of type RequestNumber.

```
public class Request
    {
        private RequestNumber Number;
        public Request()
        {
            Number = RequestNumber.CreateNext();
        }
    }
```

When running this code I can't get the following test correct. It has to create a new request thus generating a new RequestNumber but no matter what I try, the RequestNumber will always be equal to the default RequestNumber. For example, when I create 2 Requests they get number 1 and 2 and then the default will somehow be 2 as well.

```
Request request = new Request(); # gets RequestNumber 1
Request request2 = new Request(); # gets RequestNumber 2
request2.Number.Equals(default(RequestNumber)) # should be false because request2 has RequestNumber 2 and the default should be 1
```

Does anybody have a clue what I've done wrong?

Comment: Your `RequestNumber` struct doesn't even compile.

Comment: You should use meaningful names for your fields. Presumably you wanted "nextSequentialId" and "itemSequentialId" but since you decided to save on character count both stuck in single **static** field.

Comment: `_sequence = 1` doesn't have a semicolon and `number` is used where it doesn't exist; beware of not using the same code for an example as you actually tested

Comment: The function `CreateNext` references the variable `number` but does not declare it.

Comment: RequestNumber contains no (non-static) members. That means it contains no data. If you compare two things that have nothing in them, they'll always be equal.

The absence of anything Equals the absence of anything!

Comment: `static` means that that value is shared between all instances of that class or struct

Answer (score 2):

All instances of `RequestNumber` will always equal each other because RequestNumber contains no member data.